# Is this fragment valid?

Tags: c, string

```
char name[] = {};
gets(name);
```

Is this fragment valid if I want to take a name of unknown value length and store it on **name array** ?

I wanted to take a *name of unknown length* input as a string.

Comment: Not even VLAs can have their length inferred from a function call (that couldn't know whether the argument was such a magic array and couldn't act through only a decayed pointer).

Comment: Don't use `gets()`... ever... You could use `fgetc()` to load one character at a time into an array that you _grow_ using `realloc()`...

Comment: The `{}` initializer is not valid in C code.

Comment: How much space do you think is available where you are trying to read the input into?

Answer (score 1):

- `char name[] = {};` is invalid C, an initializer list must contain at least 1 item.
- `gets(name);` is invalid C, the  `gets` function was finally removed from the C language in year 2011, after it was flagged as obsolescent in the 1990s. Sources of learning teaching you to use `gets` should be retired.

There is a gcc non-standard extension allowing empty `{}` but don't write non-standard C just for the heck of it.

There is a gcc non-standard extension allowing the use of `gets` by including `stdio.h` or by compiling as `-std=c90`/`-std=c99`, but don't use that function anywhere, since it was intrinsically broken by design from day 1. Use `fgets` instead.

Even with these extensions present you didn't allocate any memory for `name` so the code is broken even then.

I strongly recommend to start using these compiler options: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)